# SQL Query in Access VBA (I assume syntax) issue

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a table in Access for which I have created a dynamic query using SQL driven from a form.

My query form and underlying table attached.
[image]

```
Public Sub QueryProductsSPECIFIC()
'General char construction
Wildcart = Chr(34) & "*" & Chr(34)
EndSQL = ";"

'SQL String Construction
StrSQLAA = "SELECT "

StrSQLAB = "ProductList.ID, ProductList.ProductCode, ProductList.ProductType, ProductList.ProductName, ProductList.UOM, ProductList.ProductMainCategory, ProductList.ProductSubCategory, ProductList.SupplierName, ProductList.SupplierProductCode, ProductList.ProductActive, ProductList.SOH, ProductList.CPExclVAT, ProductList.SPExclVAT, ProductList.VATRate, ProductList.VATAmount, ProductList.SPInclVAT, ProductList.MaxDiscount, ProductList.[GP%], ProductList.Image "

StrSQLAC = "FROM "

StrSQLAD = "ProductList "

StrSQLAE = "WHERE "

StrSQLAF = "((ProductList.ProductCode) LIKE " & Wildcart & " & [Forms]![ProductSearch]![SearchProductCode] & " & Wildcart & ")"

StrSQLAG = "((ProductList.ProductName) LIKE " & Wildcart & " & [Forms]![ProductSearch]![SearchProductName] & " & Wildcart & ")"

StrSQL = StrSQLAA & StrSQLAB & StrSQLAC & StrSQLAD & StrSQLAE & StrSQLAF & ", "& StrSQLAG

'Temp line for troubleshooting SQL Code
Debug.Print StrSQL
'Debug.Print strSQLY

'Delete query if it already exists
On Error Resume Next
DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "ProductFullListQuery"

'Create new query
Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("ProductFullListQuery", StrSQL & EndSQL)
'DoCmd.OpenQuery qdf.Name

'Release
qdf.Close
Set qdf = Nothing
```

When I exclude StrSQLAG, my query runs, when I include it, it returns zero results.  I don't know SQL well enough to know if I am messing up the syntax somewhere.  I also tried ", AND" instead of ", " after StrSQLAF , but I get the same result.

**Debug returns:**

```
SELECT ProductList.ID, ProductList.ProductCode, ProductList.ProductType, ProductList.ProductName, ProductList.UOM, ProductList.ProductMainCategory, ProductList.ProductSubCategory, ProductList.SupplierName, ProductList.SupplierProductCode, ProductList.ProductActive, ProductList.SOH, ProductList.CPExclVAT, ProductList.SPExclVAT, ProductList.VATRate, ProductList.VATAmount, ProductList.SPInclVAT, ProductList.MaxDiscount, ProductList.[GP%], ProductList.Image 
FROM ProductList 
WHERE ((ProductList.ProductCode) LIKE "*" & [Forms]![ProductSearch]![SearchProductCode] & "*"), 
((ProductList.ProductName) LIKE "*" & [Forms]![ProductSearch]![SearchProductName] & "*");
```

With my limited knowledge this looks right to me, but it obviously is not.

Comment: Not knowing exactly what you're trying to get, I would try this: `StrSQLAF & " OR " & StrSQLAG` So the whole line looks like: `StrSQL = StrSQLAA & StrSQLAB & StrSQLAC & StrSQLAD & StrSQLAE & StrSQLAF & " OR " & StrSQLAG`

Comment: Thank you Nick.  It was my comma that was messing it up.  I just substituted your OR for a AND (because I want every field's query to be evaluated against the products to get a match where all the conditions is true and VOILA! it worked.  Much appreciated.